# jQuery Get Class Name

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the class name from an selection of images when clicked.

The code below retrieves the first images class name but when I click on my other images with different class values they display the first images class.

How can I get each images class value?

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="{title}" class="bg"><img src="{image:url:small}" alt="{title}" class="{image:url:large}" /></a>
```

jQuery Code

```
    $(".bg").click(function(){
        var1 = $('.bg img').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(".bg").click(function(){
    var1 = $(this).children('img').attr('class');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's works really well. I also found that var1 = $('img', this).attr('class'); works as well but what would be the better method to use?

Comment: Both equally valid - in your case, $('img', this) might be better. If you already have the context set up though, calling [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or .find() on it is what you'll want to do.

Comment: @Jemes and @fx_: incidentally using `$('img',this)` causes jQuery to call, internally, `$(this).find('img')`: ["Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span')."](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) Which *implies* that the latter is slightly faster (albeit micro-micro-optimisation).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(".bg").click(function(){
    var1 = $(this).attr('class');
});
```

The above might, on reflection, not be quite what you're after. I'd suggest trying:

```
$('.bg img').click(  // attaches the 'click' to the image
    function(){
        var1 = $(this).attr('class');
    });
```

Or:

```
$(".bg").click(function(){
    var1 = $(this).find('img').attr('class'); // finds the 'img' inside the 'a'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that will give me the class value from the link not the image.

Comment: @Jemes, while the *first* code section would, indeed return the `class` name of the `a` the latter two code samples will return the `class` of the image; the last of the three, in particular, would work as you'd require it.